# issues with DKMS while installing nvidia drivers on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, login

I'm unable to install Nvidia driver, and got stuck in a login loop after trying to install the Nvidia driver from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa. I tried installing version 396, but I am not able to understand the error. I tried the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-396
```

I got the following error:

[image]

I'm also unable to login into my account and coming back to the login screen after putting the login credentials.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `nvidia-driver-396` or `nvidia-396` first before installing the `nvidia-driver-415`?  I think you have to remove the old driver first since the system will try to upgrade instead of remove and install the new driver.

Comment: yes. Sorry by mistake I wrote 415 . But I deleted the previous version before installing the new.

Comment: `nvidia-396` is the incorrect name for the install from the PPA.  It is `nvidia-driver-396` for the install.  You will probably now need to do the install from launching a TTY to run the install by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 to Ctr+Alt+F6.  After the installation type in reboot so that the new driver can take effect.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance . I just followed the post on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/246858#246858)

Comment: @Terrance i tried with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396` . But it is unable to locate the package `nvidia-driver-396`

Comment: OK, your question does not state what version of Ubuntu you are using and what is the Flavor of it.  Please edit your question and put in what version you are using and more details.  Also fix any discrepancies you have there.  Ubuntu 16.04 installs the NVIDIA drivers from the PPA as `nvidia-396` or whatever version you are trying to install.  Ubuntu 18.04 does the driver installation as `nvidia-driver-396`.

Comment: @Terrance I am still stuck. i have tried almost everything on this platform but nothing worked

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1121295/edit) your question and add more details like what your system type / model is, what is your video card, etc.  Any more details of errors and things that you have tried will really help us help you instead of us trying to guess at things you have tried or what will work.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh, also, you might need to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS for these drivers to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and login in your account and enter this command

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```